# Transfer large amount of data in chunks

Tags: filesystems, file-transfer

I need to copy data from one server to another however the only median we have is a small HDD. What is the best way to split up the data and merge it back on the other end without creating archives as the first server is full?

Comment: Are you sure that is the only possible solution?  What about via the network?  Is physically removing the drive a possible solution?  Or maybe temporarily adding another drive to use during archiving?

Comment: @heavyd Sorry, none of those are possible for this job

Comment: What OS are you using? Is it one file, or many files? If you are comfortable with Linux boot up an Ubuntu live-cd on each computer, and use netcat to send the file over a lan cable. Destination: `netcat -l 1234 > "/folder/file.file"`. Source: `netcat 127.0.1.2 1234 < "/folder/file.file"`. Substitute values obviously. This would save you having to do any splitting, but if you're doing more than one file it will be a pain.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified your operating system, which makes this question harder to answer.

However, [HJSplit](http://www.hjsplit.org/) is a GUI file splitter/joiner available for Windows/Linux.
For the Linux/Unix command line, there's also `split`, which can be rejoined with `cat`.  Usage instructions with an example are available on the Wikipedia page [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split_%28Unix%29).